# [Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy']

Tags: flutter

For a long time I drag without success with the problem I encounter

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final res = await dbRequest();
  print(res);
  final mySelectedEvents = (res.map((e) => GroupBy.fromJson(e))).toList();
  print(mySelectedEvents);
}

Future<List<dynamic>> dbRequest() async {
  return [
    {'date': '2022-09-17', 'eventDescp': 'azerty', 'eventTitle': 'azertyui'},
    {'date': '2022-09-17', 'eventDescp': '11', 'eventTitle': 'AZE'},
    {'date': '2022-09-17', 'eventDescp': '22', 'eventTitle': '4556'},
    {'date': '2022-09-20', 'eventDescp': '77', 'eventTitle': 'HHJ'},
    {'date': '2022-09-17', 'eventDescp': '44', 'eventTitle': 'BYYY'}
  ];
}
```

Comment: leave a snippet of the fromJson method

Comment: [{date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: azerty, eventTitle: azertyui}, {date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: 11, eventTitle: AZE}, {date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: 22, eventTitle: 4556}, {date: 2022-09-20, eventDescp: 77, eventTitle: HHJ}, {date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: 44, eventTitle: BYYY}]

Comment: i mean the method implementation

Comment: factory GroupBy.fromRawJson(String str) => GroupBy.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory GroupBy.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GroupBy(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        date: json["date"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["date"]),

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using   `final mySelectedEvents = (res.map((e) => GroupBy.fromJson(e))).toList();` to  `List<GroupBy> mySelectedEvents = (res.map((e) => GroupBy.fromJson(e))).toList();` . Now You can See All The Data In The List While Printing

Comment: I have this again  [Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy', Instance of 'GroupBy']